# What kind of music has vocals but no words

Tags: definition

There is a type of music that has vocals, but they don't actually sing words. An example is this: https://youtu.be/8Jc2j2cjoz4?t=10

Does anyone know what the name of this type of music this is?

Answer (score 1):

That specific piece *does* have lyrics[1](https://lyrics.fandom.com/wiki/Howard_Shore:The_End_Of_All_Things), though they are not in English or Latin: they are in a language created for Lord of the Rings --- probably Elvish.

As a general term, singing without words is called "vocalizing" and is present in many genres of music. Older chants and modern abstract compositions are two common types of music that involve voice without words. [2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_music)

Many dramatic choral pieces for movies are not sung in English and/or include vocalizations instead of lyrics.

Answer (score 1):

This  kind of music is orchestral + choral, meaning there is a full orchestra with a choir and to be more precise, Howard Shore used  a core 96-piece orchestra and 100-piece choir.

I'd describe those "words" as **Non-lexical vocables**. It's when someone sings, but uses  nonsense syllable like "la la la" or "ah ah ah".

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-lexical_vocables_in_music) provides some good examples from various music styles, with one of the most famous ones being [*The Great Gig in the Sky*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T13se_2A7c8) by Pink Floyd.